# Codeignighter linking mishap

Tags: php, frameworks, hyperlink

Im fairly new to codeignighter and have been trying to make a little Header, content, footer Template.

im currently having a little issue pointing to other views. Heres what i got for code

My head.php

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>TEST HEADER</title>
 </head>
```

My content (main.php)

```
<body>

  <a href="views/page1.php">Hello World</a>
  <a href="page2.php">LINK2</a>

 <br><br>
```

My footer.php

```
   the footer
 </body>
</html>
```

Now the whole deal im having is that i want to link to a inner page (page1.php), i have it setup as a php file in the views folder

page1.php

```
<?php $this->load->view('head'); ?>

    <a href="main.php">back</a>

    <br><br>

<?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

I would like to be able to make subpages like this and just inject the header and footer into them. But everytime i try linking to this page1.php from the main, i get a message "The requested URL /CI_Test/views/page1.php was not found on this server." but the file is there?

im a bit confused, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<?=site_url('page1.php')?>` in main.php:

```
  <a href="<?=site_url('page1.php')?>">Hello World</a>
```

But it's likely that your problem is due to routing and .htaccess mod_rewrite. For CodeIgniter to work, the .htaccess file tells your server to reroute all requests (with a few exceptions depending on setup) to index.php, and CodeIgniter then routes the request to a corresponding controller which renders the view.

Try reading the CI documentation, e.g. about static pages:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Comment: i tried what you said but now when i try to access the site nothing comes out :/ dont get why changing the link makes everything disappear

Comment: Are you running the site on your local computer? Or on a webhost? Can you see and edit the .htaccess file?

Comment: This question seems old and not looked after then anyway this comment can help some newbie after you check  routing and .htaccess mod_rewrite make sure you are including it with subfolder if your views are under another folder like $this->load->view('folder/head'); 
mark this as fixed and comment if its closed or explain more